# how to create wordpress user that can only view the plugin I wrote

Tags: wordpress

I have written a plugin, where pre-created users can log in to the system and configure the application. Problem is when I give them higher roles they can view other content on the back-end of the site.Such as creating posts, pages and etc. If I give law level role such as subscriber, user can not view the pluging page. They can't do any configuration.

What I need is only give permission to view my admin panel.

This is the code I create admin panel in wordpress.

```
function oscimp_admin_actions() {
     add_management_page("Pages", "My Pages", "activate_plugins", "Skill-Pages", "skills_list_admin");
}
```

I would like to create a user from subscriber and allow only to this plugin's admin panel. Can we do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this with add_cap() method of Wordpress. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_cap

Also you would like to read those articles about roles and caps: http://www.garyc40.com/2010/04/ultimate-guide-to-roles-and-capabilities/ and http://wp.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-user-permissions-and-your-plugin/, no doubt they will help you